# Up-sells and Associated Products tab error - after migration

Tags: php, mysql, magento

We have a multi store Magento installation that we moved from a VPS to a dedicated ubuntu server.

We just copied the files and transfered the database to the new server via HeidiSQL export tool.

Everything seemed to work fine, expect now we discover that the Up-sells and Associated Product tabs aren't working properly. I clicked them, it displays the "Please wait" loading screen as usual, but it just stays in the same place. Not even the url changes.

These are the two tabs we actually use, the rest of the tabs work fine. I'm sure it's not a coincidence as it's exactly the two tabs that have data in them, so I'm guessing there must be some kind of conflict.

Question is, how can I debug it? Or does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Comment: Can you maybe shorten the title of this question to, say, a five or six word summary?

Comment: Also, no one can debug a description of a problem. Debugging requires code. Can you post some?

Comment: Shortened. About the code, I don't even know where to begin. I was looking for some debug tips that could send me in the right direction.

Comment: First of all, you have to define what you mean by "not working properly". This could have any number of meanings.

Comment: It seems like there's an AJAX call in there somewhere. Can you verify that there are no javascript errors on your console? If you're using Chrome, just hit F12 and look at the bottom-right of the pop-up for a red circle with a white X.

Comment: There is in fact an error.


`POST http://www.domain.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/upsell/id/10988/key/2fbcabb46498a1138864d71778e9dc89/?isAjax=true 500 (Internal Server Error) tabs.js:203
Ajax.Request.Class.create.request tabs.js:203
Ajax.Request.addMethods.initialize tabs.js:1273
(anonymous function) tabs.js:59
klass tabs.js:7
varienTabs.showTabContent tabs.js:1362
varienTabs.tabMouseClick tabs.js:1353
(anonymous function) tabs.js:55
responder tabs.js:545`

Comment: There you go! I'm not sure which framework you're using, so I'll assume that the error lies in your "controllers/admin.php" file. Browse to `http://www.domain.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/upsell/id/10988/key/2fbcab‌​b46498a1138864d71778e9dc89/?isAjax=true` and see if you can see error output. It should tell you exactly where the error is.  If you don't see anything, check your PHP error log.

Comment: I'm using Magento. And that page just renders the controls for the upsell products without css. Which is a step forward. System.log and Exceptions.log don't display any kind of error related to this issue. I presume those are the files you were saying when you said PHP error log?

Comment: I'm not sure how your server is set up. Get in touch with your host and see if they can help you find the PHP error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a Php compability issue. The new server had a different version. Installed the same version I had on my VPS and it worked after that.

Comment: Which php and mysql version you have in which complete working?

Comment: Sorry, should have written it down. I'm off that server now, and can't really tell you which version it was running. You're having the same issue?

Comment: yes i having the same issue for crosssel, up-sells and related product. This tab is not working in magento 1.7.0.2.

Comment: Did you change your php version? That's probably it. Even if you didn't, you should downgrade/upgrade it to see if it's still not working.

Comment: Related product, Up-sells and Cross-sells product tab completely working in magento 1.6.2 but when we update magento to 1.7.0.2, its not working. In this, PHP and Mysql version are the same.